# How to use permission inside android framework?

Tags: android, permissions

I register an BroadcastReceiver to receive SMS in a SystemService, but we don't have the permisson "android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS". So how to use permission inside android framework? In the SystemService, it's context is get from ActivityManagerService.main().

```
 public void setWindowManager(WindowManagerService wm) {
    mWindowManager = wm;
}

public static final Context main(int factoryTest) {
    AThread thr = new AThread();
    thr.start();

    synchronized (thr) {
        while (thr.mService == null) {
            try {
                thr.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    ActivityManagerService m = thr.mService;
    mSelf = m;
    ActivityThread at = ActivityThread.systemMain();
    mSystemThread = at;
    Context context = at.getSystemContext();
    m.mContext = context;
    m.mFactoryTest = factoryTest;
    PowerManager pm =
        (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    m.mGoingToSleep = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "ActivityManager-Sleep");
    m.mLaunchingActivity = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "ActivityManager-Launch");
    m.mLaunchingActivity.setReferenceCounted(false);

    m.mBatteryStatsService.publish(context);
    m.mUsageStatsService.publish(context);

    synchronized (thr) {
        thr.mReady = true;
        thr.notifyAll();
    }

    m.startRunning(null, null, null, null);

    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml placed at frameworks/base/core/res

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and tried to find the best way to access a permission protected system service from another system service.

In this case the solution usually is already in the Android code, for example have a look in frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java which is using the VibratorService.java from the same package.

You can see that the calling structure is something like this:

```
long identity = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
try {
    mVibrator.cancel();
}
finally {
    Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(identity);
}
```

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html#clearCallingIdentity%28%29) clearCallingIdentity() is exactly what you need:

> Blockquote
>   Reset the identity of the incoming IPC on the current thread. This can be useful if, while handling an incoming call, you will be calling on interfaces of other objects that may be local to your process and need to do permission checks on the calls coming into them (so they will check the permission of your own local process, and not whatever process originally called you).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the following:

```
private static final String ANDROID_PERMISSION_RECEIVE_SMS = "android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS";

public void setUpPermissions() {
    PermissionInfo permissionInfo = new PermissionInfo();
    permissionInfo.name = ANDROID_PERMISSION_RECEIVE_SMS;
    getContext().getPackageManager().addPermission(permissionInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Declare the permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions) you'll need in your application's `AndroidManifest.xml`.

That permission is actually in the exact example from the docs (along with other helpful things if you [search](http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=RECEIVE_SMS&t=0) for it):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.app.myapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: The SystemService is running in the android framework, whose context is the System Context. And there is not a  AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: There probably is one somewhere, just not in the place it would be for an sdk app.

Comment: Hm yeah I misunderstood what you were asking. Have you tried poking through the source to figure out how other "system" services that need permissions get them? Even Android's own MMS app just uses a normal Service with permissions in the Manifest. See this post from Diane Hackborn: http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/f9a383ce949d1557

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps the wrong way to go about whatever you are trying to do.

Rather than cutting a new "doorway" from the outside world into a core part of the system, it might be a better idea to add a new interface to the system which SDK apps can utilize, and then write an SDK app which receives SMS and can use this new interface to accomplish something.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare permission if your system service is implemented correctly.